# How to apply three colours one by one to group of div's serially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to Apply three colours which are {red, green, blue} in order to group of div's serially. I using array with "for" loop to apply colours to div but it's not working properly.

My code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
  var len = $('.box').length;
  for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    $(this).find('.box').addClass(colors[j]);
  }

});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>demo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not do this with just CSS selectors instead of jQuery/JS?

Comment: You have fewer elements in the colors array than in the box array...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current logic is flawed as the index of the boxes will exceed the number of classes available in the array. To work around this you can use the modulo operator, `%`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
  $('.box').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass(colors[i % colors.length]);
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Also note that you can achieve the exact same effect using CSS alone with the `nth-child` selector:

```css
.box:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}
.box:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background-color: green;
}
.box:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Just saw `nth-child`, so removed my duplicate answer.

Comment: @Muthupandianc no problem, glad to help.